# How do I store multiple pictures to a single column in Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am having success uploading a single picture to a row, but for my app, the user is need to have the capability to take multiple pictures.

How to I store multiple pictures to a single column in Parse?

Do I use an array and store a list of ParseFiles?

If so, how do I do this?

Comment: simple answer you can't save multiple `PFFiles` to a single cell. you will have to learn and research pointers/relations/joint tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array to store all images in and then through a for loop create an object for each picture with a PFFile. Then store each one individually with saveInBackground. Try something like

```
func saveImages(imagesArray:NSArray){
    for var i = 0; i < imagesArray.count; i++
    {
        var objectForSave:PFObject = PFObject(className: "ClassName")
        let imageData:NSData = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagesArray.objectAtIndex(i) as! UIImage))

        var imageFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: imageData)
        imageFile.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if success{
                objectForSave.setObject(imageFile, forKey: "Image")

                objectForSave.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if success{
                      //do smth
                    }else{
                        println(error)
                    }
                })

            }else{
                println(error)
            }

            }, progressBlock: { (progress:Int32) -> Void in

        })


    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome Josh. I actually forgot the step of converting UIImage to NSData. Just edited my answer..

Comment: Hey snksnk, I updated it with your code, it works great, except my image array is not an array, but an [UIImage] array.  My code has: var images = [UIImage]() instead of imagesArray:NSArray that you specified....  There is an error which says [(UIImage)]' does not have a member named 'objectAtIndex'...

Comment: Here is a sample output of my images imageview array:   [<UIImage: 0x16edff30>, <UIImage: 0x16f16630>, <UIImage: 0x16ee8700>]

Comment: How do you populate your array? Paste the relevant code pls

Comment: I am populating it using PHAssetCollection and storing the photos with .enumerateObjectsUsingBlock method using the value from PHFetchResult

Comment: photosAsset.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock {
            object, index, stop in
            
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.synchronous = true
            options.deliveryMode = .HighQualityFormat
            
            PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(object as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 250.0, height: 250.0), contentMode: .AspectFill, options: options) {
                image, info in
                self.images.append(image)
            }
        }

Comment: images is my array, and it is declared outside the function as var images = [UIImage]()

Comment: Again, thank you for taking time out to help me.  I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure how photo assets work because I've never used them. I am not sure if this is important but why dont you just declare var images: nsmutablearray = nsmutablearray()?

Comment: When I do that, it breaks my code which handles my Photo Assets... Thank you for your help though.  It got me on the right direction. I will figure it out when I get some rest lol.