# Uploading multiple Images to Parse

Tags: swift, image, parse-platform

I am wondering if its possible to upload 10 images to parse, and then be able to display them in TableView displaying the users username.

So basically when I download them from parse  I'm guessing there needs to be something linking those images to the same user or that 1 individual post...

Not sure if this is possible, but I read these two questions and I think you can!

[How do I store multiple pictures to a single column in Parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081996/how-do-i-store-multiple-pictures-to-a-single-column-in-parse)

[Storing images from [UIImage] array to Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087095/storing-images-from-uiimage-array-to-parse)

If anyone understands what I mean, I would love your help!

Best regards.

Comment: Just so I understand, you have a list of users and each user has their own image?

Comment: @BenSullivan If a user uploads 10 images, I want to then display those 10 images in 1 cell, not in 10 individual cells

Comment: Ok, well the solution could be quite long winded but basically you'll want to embed a horizontal scrolling collectionView within each tableView cell and populate the images into that. Are you storing the user and their images into an object or just arrays?

Comment: My problem isn't display them, I haven't got there yet! at the moment I just want to be able to upload 10 images and them all be connected to the same post. Check the links i added in my question, they probably explain what I'm after better

Comment: Rather than connecting posts to users, if the users each have up to 10 photos then could you not just add the images array as a column in your Parse User class? If you do that then you can just use a PFUser Query to download the username and the relevant images for each user.

Comment: Yeh thats exactly what I'm after I think! add the images as array in 1 column! If you have any idea how to do so, I would seriously appreciate if you could give me a hand!

Comment: I presume from the other answers you were able to save an array of images successfully? This isn't something I've tried before

Comment: @BenSullivan Nope, I've been trying but just can't figure it out!

Comment: Might be be better to just have 10 separate columns and save the array issue entirely?

Comment: @BenSullivan that's an idea...But how would I add an image to the exact column? the first image I upload might just go in all the columns...I need to order the array of images and add 1st, 2nd, then 3rd etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed, you can add the array of images to a column in your User class, the code below allows you to create a new user and will take an image array and create as many columns as necessary. They will be titled "imageArray0", "imageArray1" and so on. The next time you create a user with images they will automatically be added to the corresponding columns in Parse.

**UPDATE**

Added image conversion:

```
           let user = PFUser()
           user.username = chosenUsername

            for i in imageArray.indices {
              let imageData = imageArray[i].mediumQualityJPEGNSData
              let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.JPEG", data: imageData)
                user["imageArray\(i)"] = imageFile
             }

                user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    success, error in

                    if error == nil {

                    } else {

                    }
                })
```

I also use this extension to easily convert images to various qualities:

```
extension UIImage {
var uncompressedPNGData: NSData      { return     UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)!        }
var highestQualityJPEGNSData: NSData { return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0)!  }
var highQualityJPEGNSData: NSData    { return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 0.75)! }
var mediumQualityJPEGNSData: NSData  { return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 0.5)!  }
var lowQualityJPEGNSData: NSData     { return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 0.25)! }
var lowestQualityJPEGNSData:NSData   { return
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 0.0)!  }
}
```

Comment: That was quick! :) Ok so I am using a pod DKImagePickerController to pick multiple images and then I display them on my VC. here's a screen shot of my cellForItemAtIndexPath so you can see how it is  http://i.stack.imgur.com/BdUoN.png  Don't I need to convert the images before uploading?

Comment: Asset is the array [DKAsset] where the pods put the images. then I display them, I also added and array: images = [UIImage]() to try and move the images from Asset into that (images)! confusing... But i'm not sure if I'm doing that correctly!

Comment: I've updated my answer with conversion, I'm not too sure I can help with the other issues you are having without seeing the app

Comment: Ok so I set it up http://i.stack.imgur.com/e7vXq.png its started to work. but I just checked parse and the first image is showing for all the colums..!

Comment: also for each photo it uploads it creates a new row!

Comment: That doesn't look quite right, are you able to put it up on gitHub at all?

Comment: I just realised go over it again this morning, that I did something wrong..Now this is my code http://i.stack.imgur.com/tZPHo.png  But it still only uploads the last picture in the array strangely..

Comment: Can you try it without the second for loop?

Comment: Also you're still saving the images to a Blogs class rather than into the User class

Comment: I know, but the class doesn't really matter... I shall be changing all of that afterwards..Just need to find a way to upload multiple images correctly! Driving me mad!

Comment: Did you try removing the second loop? Are you certain that your images array contains different images?

Comment: what do you mean second loop, and ye my images are definetly different

Comment: You have "for i in imageArray.indices {" inside another "for i in imageArray.indices {" you shouldn't need to do this twice and could be causing an issue. If you can upload to github I could take a look at it

Comment: Well spotted I completly missed that! It worked..! But only uploads 4 images any idea?

Comment: Awesome! That seems odd, best thing to find the error is to insert lots of prints inside and outside the loop so you can tell how many times things are running etc...

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure that is possible but is unnecessary for two reasons:

1. Speed of query when you want to retrieve the images array
2. You can save each image under the same row but separately under the Image x number

and finally you can't save a UIImage Array it will have to be a NSData Array so convert the UIImages into NSData's using

```
let image1 : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage][0]!)!
let image2 : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage][1]!)!
let image3 : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage][2]!)!
let imageArray : [NSData] = [image1, image2, image3]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! My issue is just I dont understand how to save multiple image as a Array in 1 column in parse...